# How to Launch another Application within my own application in Android?

Tags: android

[image: See Image]

I want to develop an Android application with two application running in one activity. The requirement is that I want to divide my activity into two parts as shown in the image. It will have an upper portion and bottom portion. Upper and down portion will show the list of apps to launch. The user select any app in upper portion will run in the above part. Meanwhile if user selects any application from the bottom portion would run the application in bottom part. 
I have searched for this but could not found any solution.

Please help me in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to develop an Android application with two application running in one activity.

That is not possible, sorry. The OS can offer multi-window, as Android itself does starting with 7.0 and select older devices from Samsung, LG, etc. do. An app cannot embed another app's UI inside its own.

Comment: So how do we make our app to be used as mutli window? and also the other app should also run as multi window.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanKhan: "So how do we make our app to be used as mutli window?" -- it happens by default, on Android 7.0+. "and also the other app should also run as multi window" -- that is up to the developers of the other app, not you. While it is difficult for an app to block itself from running in split-screen mode, it is possible.